# MIPS Assembly - Storing user input into a stack

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I'm trying to store user input into the stack, and when the user enters in 0 the program will stop receiving input and print out all of the numbers in order that the user added, not including the zero. I'm not sure how to go about this correctly. Here is my code thus far.

```
.data
prompt: .ascii "Please enter numbers, enter (0) to exit: "

.text

main:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt
syscall


do:
li $v0, 5
syscall
addi $sp, $sp, -4 # Move stack four bytes down -- MAYBE MAKE SOME OF COUNTER TO KEEP TRACK OF HOW MUCH DATA NEEDS TO BE STORED IN STACK??
sw $v0, 0($sp) # Places contents of $t0 into first spot into the stack -- THINK I NEED TO CHANGE THIS TO ACCOMADATE CHANGE IN MEMORY??
#while
bne $t0, 0, do # Branch to print section if input = 0

print:
lw $t0, 0($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 4
# Do printing instructions here from stack

end:
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Any recommendations or help is greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: You seem to be on the right track. Since you need to print in same order, I suggest you store the original value of `$sp` somewhere. Then walk the numbers using that copy until you hit current value of `$sp`. PS: you want to move your `do` label up so it reloads `$v0` which is of course destroyed by the input.

Comment: Ok that seems to make sense, so store where the initial value of the stack starts i.e. 0($sp), then decrement by 4 store new value etc, until the value equals zero, move the stack pointer to initial value and decrement by 4 the amount of times the user entered input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be probably closed as "unclear what you're asking" (your question is not a perfect fit for stackoverflow kind of questions ... to put it nicely), but I personally don't have problem with these broad style biased questions, just the answer will be not very useful for others, so better put some effort to exploit it for yourself at least.

```
...
li $v0, 5

do:
```

What is in `v0` here (i.e. which service is asked from MARS)? Five? And upon second loop iteration?

```
syscall
move $t0, $v0 # Places input in $t0
```

Why? (*)

```
addi $sp, $sp, -4 # Move stack four bytes down MAYBE MAKE SOME OF COUNTER TO KEEP TRACK OF HOW MUCH DATA NEEDS TO BE STORED IN STACK??
```

Your newly edited comment addresses the biggest deficiency. Yes, you are blindly subtracting from `sp` without having any way to recover it later. Keeping counter is one of possible ways, other is to store original `sp` somewhere (the `$sX` registers are handy), then `stored_bytes = original_sp - sp;` (and `count = stored_bytes>>2;`, but you may even not need the count directly, if you want just to print the values back, using original_sp value should be enough then).

```
sw $t0, 0($sp) # Places contents of $t0 into first spot into the stack -- THINK I NEED TO CHANGE THIS TO ACCOMADATE CHANGE IN MEMORY??
```

Yes, it stores value in `t0` to memory at address `sp`. I'm not sure what your edited comment means, what is worrying you.

```
while:
```

Unused label, rather turn it into comment, as you don't need it.

```
beq $t0, $zero, print # Branch to print section if input = 0
j do
```

This can be probably turned into branch-when-not-zero (`bne` is MIPS instruction IIRC?), then you don't need `j` anywhere, when `print:` code will follow.

(lot more advanced tip/info, feel free to skip) Also make sure your MARS simulator has delayed branching OFF in options (as is by default, making the simulation of MIPS unreal, but easier to understand and learn to code). On real MIPS CPU you must put branching code 1 instruction ahead of where the branch will actually be effective (or avoid that by using `nop` after each branch, which is valid solution in some rare cases, and lame in others).

```
print:

# Do printing instructions here from stack
```

So, try something.

You should also try your code in debugger, using single-step over instruction, watching register and memory content, to get better grasp how CPU works.

* - my biggest personal mental "break-through" when I was learning programming as kid (basically I learned programming in assembly, did some BASIC before for a short while, but switched to assembly very early, as I wanted all the performance of that 3.5MHz Z80 CPU (that speed is not a typo)) was, when I finally realized that once you have theoretical formula of the calculation clean enough, you can simply write it 1:1 into computer instructions. There's no need to dance around and add additional cruft of code, to make it look similar to something else, etc. All you need is very clear and deep understanding, what is it you want to actually calculate.

In your case you want to store inputted value into stack memory. The inputted value was/is in `v0`. Why do you involve additional `t0` register? Just store it `sw $v0, 0($sp)` (after the `sp` is adjusted by `addi` of course).

The same goes probably for the rest of your code and effort. Take a paper and pencil, and try first to put down what you are actually trying to achieve. The missing counter/sp-restoration would become obvious, once you would try to create the print code (you would notice there is no value to base end of printing on).

Remember, that weeks of coding can save hours of planning.

Comment: Awesome thanks so much for the input, I'll look over everything I'm doing and let you know what is going on. My biggest issue is just storing into the stack without knowing how many inputs the user will enter. That is why I was thinking of some sort of counter.

Comment: Well, that's what stack is actually quite good choice for, you may go dynamically down into it for as many items, as user enters (unless the user is really malicious, and fills up all available stack space, then you may hit stack-overflow situation - pun intended). But once you have all those values in stack, and `sp` modified some-many-times, you have to have some mechanism to revert that back, first to print the values back, secondly it is expected from any decent subroutine to restore stack properly upon exit (your code is not subroutine, but whole app, still practice makes perfect).

Comment: If you will store original stack pointer somewhere, it may work both as starting point for printing (just needs -4), and also after printing you may set `sp` directly back to original value, effectively "releasing" all those inputted values from stack. (the values stay written in memory of course, until the following code will use the stack space for its own values).

Comment: For This Code:     sw $v0, 0($sp) # Places contents of $t0 into first spot into the stack, everytime the user enters a number wouldn't it just replace the the number at the top of the stack?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that comment. Stack is ordinary memory. `sw` is "store word into memory". The usage of `sp` register to track down particular area of memory as *"stack"* is more like convenience of assembler and programmers, CPU doesn't see it like that, for CPU it's ordinary memory addressed through address in register $30 (or which one is aliased `sp`). There's nothing magical about "stack". Again, you have MARS, use the debugger, single-step over instructions, open window with memory at address of stack-16, etc... WATCH first and try to comprehend, what happens (+read inst. docs).

Comment: About edited comment: but you do `addi $sp,$sp,-4` every iteration, so the "top of the stack" (address in `sp`) moves every time, pointing to different memory.

Comment: Ok, thanks again for input, it doesn't seem that I have an $sX register to store the $sp address. So I don't know how to go about storing the initial address of $sp

Comment: Table 5.3: http://www.cs.uwm.edu/classes/cs315/Bacon/Lecture/HTML/ch05s03.html  ... there are 8 registers $16 - $23 with alias `$s<number>` .. by X I meant the 0-7 number. Pick any. And to be super correct, you should first store the original value somewhere (stack is common choice), and restore it before ending your code back. Doesn't matter, as you are not creating subroutine, but stand-alone code, still practice makes... (and shows, that you understand that `$sX` registers should be preserved by the common MIPS calling *convention* = programmer has to obey it, assembler+machine don't care).

Comment: I tried using the lw, la, li, sw methods, but get this error each time: "lw": Too few or incorrectly formatted operands. Expected: sw $t1,-100($t2), when I try to store sw $s0, $sp

Comment: Can you recall what did you remove from your original code?  `move $t0, $v0` What is `t0` and `v0` in that register table? Both are registers. In MIPS assembly to copy value from one register to other you can use pseudo-instruction `move` (it's not real instruction, the real code will be either `add $dst, $src, $zero` or `or $dst, $src, $zero` ... which both do "copy value from "src" register into "dst" register ... but "move" sounds a bit more readable, especially if you are familiar with assembly of other CPUs).